# Is it possible to get the address of a variable while doing mathematical operations with it in the same line

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, return-value, rvalue

I was implementing a C function to do manipulations of strings.

At the end I had to return pointer to static string but before that the first element of the string had to be set to '\0'

```
char *funct(...)
{
    static char string[30];
    .
    . //do some manipulations and possibly return here
    .
    string[0] = '\0';
    return string;
}
```

Everything works absolutely fine to this point, but then I wanted to merge the last two lines :

```
char *funct(...)
{
    static char string[30];
    .
    . //do some manipulations and possibly return here
    .
    return &(string[0] = '\0');
}
```

Then I got the error "lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand".
I presume that's so because the compiler threats everithing within the brackets as a number, not a variable and as we all know you can't have address of just a number ( "return &('\0');" is wrong).

My question is absolutely inessential but still I'm eager to know if you can trick the compiler(gcc in my case) to treat the content in the brackets as a variable and not a number

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The result of the expression `string[0] = '\0'` is `'\0'`. You can't take address of a value. Don't save lines.

Comment: Please don't merge the last two lines. Keep the code readable and sane. "Code golfing" has no place in professional programming.

Comment: No, because the evaluation of `string[0] = '\0'` is not stored at an address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Everything works absolutely fine to this point

Yep, code looks fine so far.

> but then I wanted to merge the last two lines

Why? That's pointless.

> Then I got the error "lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand". I presume that's so because the compiler threats everithing within the brackets as a number

No, it is because the compiler treates everything within the brackets as the result of the `=` operator. In order to take the address of something, it must be a *lvalue* - an addressable memory location where a variable is allocated.

Some operators in C return a result which is a lvalue, some don't. The `=` operator does not. From the standard:

> An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the left operand. An
>   assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment, but is not
>   an lvalue.

So you shouldn't do this. Keep the code as it was and don't change anything:

```
string[0] = '\0';
return string;
```

> ...but still I'm eager to know if you can trick the compiler

Eh, well C allows all manner of crazy stuff. But that doesn't mean that you should do it. Some examples of code you should not write:

```
// BAD, OBFUSCATED CODE, DON'T USE THESE

return *string = '\0', string;

return &string[*string = '\0'];

return &(0<:string:>=0)<:string:>;
```

Comment: Wow almost everyday I am amazed at C, today is no exception. Could you explain the last return statement("return &(0<:string:>=0)<:string:>;") - I have never seen anything like this(it's kinda like inline if without half of the arguments)

Comment: Ah.. these are the [digraphs](https://developerinsider.co/what-is-digraphs-trigraphs-and-tokens-c-cpp-programming-language/) got confused at first too..

Comment: @HristoMitrev It's a purposely obfuscated line with the intention of writing silly code. ["Solution"](https://godbolt.org/z/RjSBD3). Basically you have to be aware of [this old trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a).

Answer (score 1):

If you want such a compound return statement  then just use the comma operator

```
return string[0] = '\0', &string[0];
```

Or (that is the same)

```
return string[0] = '\0', string;
```

Or you can enclose the expression in parentheses.

```
return ( string[0] = '\0', string );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to merge those two lines, consider writing a function with a meaningful name, instead of obfuscating your code (or try to somehow "trick" the compiler)

```
char *cleared(char *str)
{
    *str = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

So that you could use it like

```
char *funct(/*...*/)
{
    static char string[30];
    /*
        do some manipulations and possibly return here
    */
    return cleared(string);
}
```

Comment: OP's original code is still superior to this though :)

Comment: @Lundin The first (I'd say zero) version of this answer started with: "If you *really*, *really* want to merge..." ;)